# Why does append overwrite the list with the element being added?

Tags: python, numpy

I've been attempting to update two lists using this code, where numpy has been imported as `np` and where spkCount is an 8 x 10 numpy array containing either `1.0` or `0.0`:

```
mSpikes = []
stdSpikes = []
for line in spkCount:
    if line[10:-1].all() == 0:
        sample = line[0:9]
    else:
        sample = line

    m = np.mean(sample)
    std = np.std(sample)
    mSpikes.append(m)
    stdSpikes.append(std)
```

When I check `mSpikes` and `stdSpikes`, I find that they contain the following data:

```
In [52]: stdSpikes
Out[52]: [3.2317865716108862]

In [53]: mSpikes
Out[53]: [53.333333333333336]
```

Can anybody explain why this is happening and suggest a course of action?  Thank you.

EDIT:  I should mention that I checked if the for loop was iterating properly and it is.  The if/else statement is also being processed as expected.  The problem really does appear to be related to a numpy interaction with list.append...

Comment: Unrelated to question but, in Python it is common to compare with False instead of 0

Comment: @campos.ddc:  indeed, but I felt it was clearer to use `== 0`, since the data is numerical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.append()` does not overwrite the list it operates on. It seems far more likely that your loop is simply only running once, or running separately from the rest of your code.

Comment: These were my thoughts exactly, so I checked.  The loop is running 8 times (as expected), and enters the if/else statement as expected.

Comment: Try printing out the contents of the lists on each iteration, then.

Comment: Amber, I've tried that as well.  Here's the output in case I missed something:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/910471/

Comment: No, I meant, the output lists - `mSpikes` and `stdSpikes`.

Comment: your intuition was correct!  The problem came from copying the text from my text editor to ipython.  The for loop was being run independently, and only then were the np.mean and np.std calls being made.  Thanks!  I'm accepting your answer!

Comment: IPython has the `%paste` and `%cpaste` functions to help with exactly this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question concerns `mSpikes` having only one elemement, altough preformed each iteration. `appand()` really appends to the list, it doesn't overrun the previous value. I would suggest to check on `spkCount` - that should be a range, perhaps it contains only one item.

Comment: I did this initially.  There are 8 elements in spkCount, each of which is iterated over as expected.